# Postgresql query substract from one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, calculation

I have a one tables in Postgresql and cannot find how to build a query.
The table contains columns nr_serii and deleteing_time. I trying to count nr_serii and substract from this positions with deleting_time.
My query:

```
select nr_serii , count(nr_serii ) as ilosc,count(deleting_time) as ilosc_delete
from MyTable 
group by nr_serii, deleting_time
```

output is:

```
+--------------------+
| "666666";1;1       |
| "456456";1;0       |
| "333333";3;0       |
| "333333";1;1       |
| "111111";1;1       |
| "111111";3;0       |
+--------------------+
```

The part of table with raw data:

```
+--------------------------------+
| "666666";"2020-11-20 14:08:13" |
| "456456";""                    |
| "333333";""                    |
| "333333";""                    |
| "333333";""                    |
| "333333";"2020-11-20 14:02:23" |
| "111111";""                    |
| "111111";""                    |
| "111111";"2020-11-20 14:08:04" |
| "111111";""                    |
+--------------------------------+
```

And i need substract column ilosc and column ilosc_delete
example:

nr_serii:333333 ilosc:3-1=2

Expected output:

```
+-------------+
| "666666";-1 |
| "456456";1  |
| "333333";2  |
| "111111";2  |
| ...         |
+-------------+
```

I think this is very simple solution for this but i have empty in my head.

Comment: Please provide sample data as well.

Comment: Please re-post your data as formatted text - [no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). A good text formater is at [Senseful Solutions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Paste the results from there into  question between lines containing just ```. Additionally post the expected output from that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you want now.  You want to subtract the number where `deleting_time` is not null from the ones where it is null:

```
select nr_serii,
       count(*) filter (where deleting_time is null) - count(deleting_time) as ilosc_delete
from MyTable 
group by nr_serii;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8dc4f7d9650a7e0d2a4b941a109abc84) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Almost, becouse i updated my post and nr_seri:333333 in table is 4times, 3 as without deleted and 1 times is deleted, so i expect nr_serii:333333 count is 2

Comment: @miszcsu . . . Isn't what this returns?

Comment: No, this query returns nr_serii(333333) is 3, but i expected 2. The algoritm of program is that: every line with nr_serii increase stock, but when i decrease stock program add another line with nr_serii and fill the column deleteing_time.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - perfect solution! This is exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot.I didnt see previous when  you update your answer.